# Client Side Timeout is not working in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am developing an angular js application, In which I am implementing some logic to timeout for a http service.Below is the code snippet on which i am working :-

```
 var wkUrl = "api/" + 'Customers';  // Gets All customers for -api stands for the url.
        return $http({
            params: {
                Title: title,
                FirstName: firstName,
                LastName: lastName,
                DateOfBirth: dateOfBirth,
                Email: emailAddress,
                ServiceNumber: serviceNumber,
                FaxNumber: faxNumber,
                PageSize: 10
            },
            url: wkUrl,
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 10
        }).then(success, fail)
        function success(resp) {
            return resp.data; //Return the customer list data.
        }
        function fail(error) {
            var msg = "Error getting customer list: " + error;

            log.logError(msg, error, null, true);
            throw error; // so caller can see it
        }



$httpBackend.whenGET(new RegExp('api\/Customers?.*?')).respond(function (method, url) { $timeout(function () {var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open('GET', 'app/test-data/customerListResponse.js', false);
 request.send(null);
          return [request.status, request.response, {}]; }, 1000); });
```

By using above code when I run the application I am not able to time out the services using " timeout: 10" and "$timeout" in httpbackend. Please have look and let me know if you require more information on this

Note :
I just want to Enhance service templates to have a timeout on all calls to the server. For example, I am having a message box which should get displayed if the call exceeds the timeout value made to a service to perform any action. Also i have tried to use timeout in $httpbackend but no luck till now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Be careful, timeout is in millisecond so for 10s it should be 10000ms ... don't think that will solve your problem but 10 seems to be a very small value to me.

Comment: what exactly is the result you expected?

Comment: Can you give use more details about what is happening ? and what you expect :D

Comment: I just want to Enhance service templates to have a timeout on all calls to the server. For example, I am having a message box which should get displayed if the call exceeds the timeout value made to a service to perform any action. Also i have tried to use timeout in $httpbackend but no luck till now.

Comment: No Answer till now Quite depressing :(